# How to query on binary_id field or string?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am trying to write an Ecto query where the argument can be either an ID or another field, in this case a username.  For example, something like this:

```
from(u in User, where: (u.id == ^id_or_username or u.username == ^id_or_username) and is_nil(u.deleted_at))
```

The problem is that when the string `id_or_username` is not a valid binary_id, Ecto raises an error:

```
     ** (Ecto.Query.CastError) lib/myproject/accounts.ex:55: value `"user1@email.com"` cannot be dumped to type :binary_id in query:
                                                                                                                       
     from u0 in MyProject.Accounts.User,                                                                                                                                                                                                          
       where: (u0.id == ^"user1@email.com" or u0.username == ^"user1@email.com") and is_nil(u0.deleted_at),
       select: u0
```

How can I make this work?

One solution I thought of is to check if the string is a binary_id and query differently, but that's not the most elegant approach.  Nonetheless is there a function in Ecto to do such a thing?  How can you determine if a string is an Ecto binary_id?  I could regex check it but would rather not do that.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to check for the binary being valid [`Ecto.UUID`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.UUID.html), would be to use [`Ecto.UUID.cast/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.UUID.html#cast/1).

```elixir
iex|1 ▸ Ecto.UUID.generate() |> Ecto.UUID.cast()
{:ok, "a9f44567-e031-44f1-aae6-972d7aabbb45"}
iex|2 ▸ "foo" |> Ecto.UUID.cast()
:error
```

---

For the issue you experience, one might use a macro.

```elixir
defmacrop id_eq?(u, value) do
  case Ecto.UUID.cast(value) do
    {:ok, _} -> quote(do: fragment("u.id == ?", unquote(value)))
    :error -> quote(do: fragment("u.username == ?", unquote(value)))
  end
end

from(u in User, where: id_eq?(u, ^id_or_username))
```

More info on [custom macros](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#fragment/1-defining-custom-functions-using-macros-and-fragment).